# Cannot use DoubleAnimation.SetValue method in Windows 8 store App

Tags: c#, windows, storyboard

Here is my XAML code,

```
     <Grid>
         <Grid.Resources>
              <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                   <DoubleAnimation x:Name="myDoubleAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True"/>
               </Storyboard>
          </Grid.Resources>

          <Grid x:Name="op_food" PointerEntered="op_PointerEntered">
                <TextBlock Text="Food"/>
          </Grid>

          <Grid x:Name="op_cineplex" PointerEntered="op_PointerEntered">
               <TextBlock Text="Cineplex"/>
          </Grid>
     </Grid>
```

And C# function,

```
    private void op_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myStoryboard.Stop();
        Grid myGrid = (Grid)sender;
        myDoubleAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty,myGrid.Name);
        myStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

Now this is the link I have followed to do this task and the intellisense could not locate storyboard ->
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/26/target-multiple-objects-properties-with-one-animation-silverlight.aspx

So where i am wrong in this code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `Storyboard.TargetNameProperty`, not "TargetProperty" (you're attempting to set the name of the element whose property to animate, not the property name itself).

```
myDoubleAnimation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, myGrid.Name);
```

Comment: This is the problem I am facing ....Whenever I write Storyboard and its associated property it shows this error:
The name 'Storyboard' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry my bad...I am not including Media.Animation in the program

Comment: I am including the Media.Animation to the project but still face this problem....